# ASP.NET Multiple web.config file

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I'm creating simple application using asp.net for patient Management System. I have one login page which collect User name and password. Based on that Credentials i want redirect Three pages Called Doctors,Patient or Admin. I Used three Folder for those three pages. And separate Web.Config files other than root web.config file. I placed all the authentication and authorization elements inside those web.config file. But when i deployed this application I got some Errors. Why can't i use several web.config file in one application Or is there any easy way to achieve this task

thanks in advanced !

Comment: You need to provide information regarding which error you got etc, if you need help.

Answer (score 0):

Web.Config is all about the site, not the user's role.

Let's think about the elements of the web.config file which you want to be different based on the user's role.

If there are different database credentials, for example, store all of them in your web.config and load the appropriate one into Session() based on the logged-in user's role.